# jQuery Ajax - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have below Ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mltSelectActiveStatus").multipleSelect({
        placeholder: "Active Status",
        filter: true,
        onClose: function () {
        FilterActiveStatus($("#mltSelectActiveStatus").multipleSelect("getSelects"));
        }
    });
</script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    function FilterActiveStatus(activeStatusID) {
        var paramList = '{"activeStatusIDs":"' + activeStatusID + '"}';

        alert(paramList);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AddServers.aspx/FilterByActiveStatus",
            data: paramList, //{activeStatusIDs: "' + activeStatusIDs + '" }, //activeStatusIDs,//' //
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
            alert("OK");
            },
            error: AjaxFailed
        });
    }

    function AjaxFailed(result) {
        alert("hello1");
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }

</script>
```

and code-behind method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string FilterByActiveStatus(int activeStatusIDs)
{
    string status = "";
    AddServers addServers = new AddServers();
    DataSet ds = addServers.GetComparedDevices();

    var servers = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .Select(s => new
            {
                id = s.Field<int>("ID"),
                deviceID = s.Field<int>("DeviceID"),
                serverName = s.Field<string>("ServerName"),
                serverIPAddress = s.Field<string>("ServerIPAddress"),
                activeStatus = s.Field<string>("ActiveStatus"),
                activeStatusID = s.Field<int>("ActiveStatusID"),
                serverDNSName = s.Field<string>("ServerDNSName"),
            }).Where(s => s.activeStatusID == activeStatusIDs).ToList();

    addServers.gvServers.DataSource = servers;
    addServers.gvServers.DataBind();
    status = "OK";
    return status;
}
```

But I am receiving error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

I checked method separately and it works properly. I also checked added:

> alert(paramList);
>   and it returns proper values.

I am using [MULTIPLE SELECT](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#documentation)

Comment: Does request hit C# code?

Comment: @husnain_sys: I've added break point in c# method and it was hit.

Comment: Right, and what happened.... what was the exception?

Comment: I've noticed error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on line "addServers.gvServers.DataSource = servers;"

Comment: what is gvServers in your addserver class?

Comment: Surely it must be a collection. anyway can you put break point on that line and see if it is null.

Comment: @Zaki: I checked and variable "servers" contains rows.

Comment: check gvServers that is null !

Comment: @Zaki - yes, gvServers is null. So question - how can I bind data in static method?

Comment: You cannot use asp.net controls in static methods. Create a list or a collection populate it and assign it to gridview http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/bind-gridview-using-jquery or see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788827/dynamically-populate-asp-net-gridview-from-jquery-ajax-call